# Move the menu item to the bottom when the mobile version of the site

Tags: html, sass

I have a menu, I showed it below

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <a href="/1">1</a>
        <a href="/2">2</a>
        <a href="/3">3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/4">4</a>
        <a href="/5">5</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My scss styles for my menu

```
nav {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex; 
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      user-select: none;

      div > a {
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 10px;
      }

      a {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: rem(16);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px;
        color: $blueSemi;
        cursor: default;
      }
    }
```

How my menu is displayed in the browser

[image]

I want to place item No. 3 at the bottom of the page when the user accessed the site from the phone, as shown below.

[image]

The easiest method to solve the problem is to create a new element, hide element number 3 in the menu and display a new element at the bottom of the page when the user entered the site from a mobile phone.

I want to use one element, how can I use one element per page. How can this be done?

Comment: do you want it fixed in the bottom position? easiest way would be to at mobile size give it a position of `fixed` and position it in the bottom right corner

Comment: Yes, I tried it that way, but it didn't end in success

Comment: What do you mean? why didnt it work? what happened

Comment: I believe there is now simple way to achieve that. All solutions will have their pitfalls. In such cases I found that creating two elements is really the easiest way to avoid problems with styles in future

Comment: When I set the menu item to fixed, and set the bottom 0 property. The menu item was not at the bottom of the page

Comment: Actually there is better solution for that problem: Ask designer to rebuild that part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of what your looking for

```css
nav {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex; 
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      user-select: none;
      
}
    
a {
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: rem(16);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px;
        color: black;
        cursor: default;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
 }
 
 @media(max-width: 769px) {
   a:nth-child(3) {
      position: fixed;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      right: 10px;
      bottom: 10px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<nav>
    <div>
        <a href="/1">1</a>
        <a href="/2">2</a>
        <a href="/3">3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/4">4</a>
        <a href="/5">5</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

so I am selecting the 3rd list item along using `:nth-child(3)` (you could be more precise and give your 3rd menu item an ID but if you know your always going to move the third menu item to the bottom nth-child will work) giving it a position of `fixed` then I am positioning it `10px` to the right and `10px` to the bottom. Obviously you can change the positioning to how you like it

Comment: This is what I wanted to achieve myself

Comment: @MegaRoks glad I could help